# How to mock method to return value X at first call, and Y on rest calls?

Tags: phpunit

How to mock method to return value X at first call, and Y on rest calls?

Below solution works, but I don't want to write `$Y` so many times:

```
$o->expects($this->any())
      ->method('foo')
      ->will($this->onConsecutiveCalls($X, $Y, $Y, $Y, $Y, $Y));
```

Below solution will return `$Y` everytime:

```
$o->expects($this->any())
    ->method('foo')
    ->will($this->returnValue($Y));
$o->expects($this->at(0))
    ->method('foo')
    ->will($this->returnValue($X));
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using an anonymous function within PHPUnit's `returnCallback` function instead of `onConsecutiveCalls`. However, this is more lines of code than just simply typing $Y for each return value, so I'd only use the below version if **every** call to doSomething after the first call needs to return the same value any number of times:

```
class Example
{
    function doSomething() { }
}

// within your test class
public function testConsecutiveCallbacks()
{
    $counter = 0;
    $stub = $this->createMock(Example::class);
    $stub
        ->method('doSomething')
        ->will($this->returnCallback(function () use (&$counter) {
            $counter++;
            if ($counter == 1) {
                return 'value for x';
            }
            return 'value for y';
        }));
    $this->assertEquals('value for x', $stub->doSomething());
    $this->assertEquals('value for y', $stub->doSomething());
    $this->assertEquals('value for y', $stub->doSomething());
    $this->assertEquals('value for y', $stub->doSomething());
}
```